# Error changing compiler version - why so?

Tags: android, sdk

I am working on an application in android studio, when I want to change the compiler version to 26 it gives me the following error:

5-8: 13: AAPT: error: resource android: attr / dialogCornerRadius not found.

With a link that sends me to the following code:

```
<resources>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat"/>
<style name="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light"/>
<style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
</style>
<style name="Base.V28.Theme.AppCompat.Light" parent="Base.V26.Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- We can use the platform styles on API 28+ -->
    <item name="dialogCornerRadius">?android:attr/dialogCornerRadius</item>
</style>
```

My app file code:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.ocr"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
//image crop library
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.8.+'
//image to text google library
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 5-8: 13: AAPT: error: resource android: attr / dialogCornerRadius not
>   found.

You should use **`compileSdkVersion 28`** .

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion  28.0.3
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
}
```